# Group by object property in java flux

Tags: java, reactive-programming, project-reactor

Given the following data structure `Data` and `Flux<Data>` what is idiomatic way to achieve grouping into series of lists based on some property:

```
import org.reactivestreams.Publisher;
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.function.Predicate;

class Scratch {
    private static class Data {
        private Integer key;
        private String value;

        public Data(Integer key, String value) {
            this.key = key;
            this.value = value;
        }

        public Integer getKey() {
            return key;
        }

        public String getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        public static Data of(Integer key, String value) {
            return new Data(key, value);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return value;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Flux<Data> test = Flux.just(
                Data.of(1, "Hello"),
                Data.of(1, "world"),
                Data.of(2, "How"),
                Data.of(2, "are"),
                Data.of(2, "you"),
                Data.of(3, "Bye"));
        test.bufferUntil(new Predicate<Data>() {
            Integer prev = null;
            @Override
            public boolean test(Data next) {
                boolean collect = prev != null && !Objects.equals(prev, next.getKey());
                prev = next.getKey();
                return collect;
            }
        }, true).subscribe(e -> System.out.println(e.toString()));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[Hello, world]
[How, are, you]
[Bye]
```

I am aware of groupBy function on Flux, but this gives me again a Flux, not a list. Current solution I have described above works, but it does not feel 100% idiomatic because I had to use anonymous class instead of lambda. I could have use lambda and AtomicReference outside from lambda, but that too does not feel 100% right. Any suggestions?

Comment: You can just replace the anonymous inner class with lamda function, can't you? And you could use the groupby operator and then iterate over the flux of grouped fluxes

Comment: How would you store `prev` in lambda? I have no idea how to use groupby operator (in my context) :(

Answer (score 6):

You can also use `collectMultimap` which allows you to have `Map<K, Collection<T>`. In this case `collectMultimap` will return: `Mono<Map<Integer,Collection<Data>>>`:

```
 test.collectMultimap( Data::getKey )
     .subscribe( dataByKey -> System.out.println( dataByKey.toString() ) );
```

Output:

```
{1=[Hello, world], 2=[How, are, you], 3=[Bye]}
```

Comment: That does not work in our case, due to amount of data we would need to hold in memory.

Comment: I am just blind. First link after description of my problem. Saved 2 days. Working like a charm.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a solution using groupBy operator. I have grouped the data by the common key. The groupBy operator gives me a Flux of GroupedFlux. GroupedFlux is a subclass of Flux, so I apply flatMap and convert an individual groupedFlux to a `List<Data>` using the collectList operator. Like this, I get a `Flux<List<Data>>`, which I then subscribe to and print, as asked by you.

```
test.groupBy(Data::getKey)
                .flatMap(Flux::collectList)
                .subscribe(listOfStringsHavingDataWithSameKey -> System.out.println(listOfStringsHavingDataWithSameKey.toString()));
```

Do checkout the documentations for [Flux](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html) and [GroupedFlux](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/GroupedFlux.html).